# Oracle - Trigger is created, but gives error anytime data is updated

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm creating the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_UpdateTrainingDelivery
    AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF STARTDATE
    ON TPM_TRAININGPLAN
    BEGIN
      UPDATE TPM_PROJECTVERSION V
        SET TRAININGDELIVERYSTART = (SELECT MIN(STARTDATE) FROM TPM_TRAININGPLAN WHERE PROJECTID=V.PROJECTID AND VERSIONID=V.VERSIONID AND TRAININGPLANTYPE='prescribed')
    END;
```

When I create it, I get a warning:

```
Warnings: ---> 
   W (1): Warning: execution completed with warning
          <---
```

However, it's still created it anyway.  When I then modify a row in TPM_TRAININGPLAN, I get an error:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 12-12 ------------------------
 ORA-04098: trigger 'TPMDBO.TRIGGER_UPDATETRAININGDELIVERY' is invalid and failed re-validation
 Script line 12, statement line 1, column 7
```

Is there something wrong with my trigger?  I can run the UPDATE statement in the trigger by itself and it runs fine, so I don't think there's anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are missing a semicolon at the end of your `UPDATE` statement.

If you query `USER_ERRORS`, you'll get the same error information that SQL*Plus will give you with the `SHOW ERRORS` command without needing to have access to SQL*Plus.

```
SELECT line, position, text
  FROM user_errors
 WHERE name = 'TRIGGER_UPDATETRAININGDELIVERY'
 ORDER BY sequence
```

Comment: Yup, that's definitely the bug!  If I put the semi-colon in, Aqua freaks out because I guess it thinks I'm running two different statements and I get an invalid statement error.  I mistook that as an actual error with my trigger syntax, and removed the semi-colon.  I ran this all with Visual Studio (with the semicolon as you mentioned) and all is perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

What was the error being reported during compilation?

```
SQL> show errors trigger trigger_updatetrainingdelivery
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have remote access to the server and do not have SQLPlus access..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: FYI, SQL*Plus can access remote servers over a TNS listener (the same way whatever you are using accesses it). I dare say this is the normal way to use SQL*Plus. If you install Oracle Client on your machine, it should work (at least after runnning netca or manually editing tnsnames.ora)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out.  It's actually a bug in Aqua Data Studio, which I'm using to run the query.  For some reason, it doesn't handle semi-colons within the triggers correctly.  I will report this bug, but I did find a workaround:

```
File->Options->General
Uncheck: ';' Statement separator
```